# Do I need my own domain with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

My application is to use the Google App Engine to provide an embarrassingly parallel computation (and to serve the results to www-browsers).  I've been through the Google App Engine "getting started" tutorial but I'm not sure if I need to register my own domain.  Do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You can get at your app using the URL `<<your-app-id>>.appspot.com`. If you later want to wire that up to a separate domain that you own, you can do that, too.